# Android Studio2.0 error while running

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0

```
Error while executing: am start -n "com.*************************" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(java.lang.String) (tried Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get and Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get__Ljava_lang_String_2)
    at android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(Native Method)
    at android.os.SystemProperties.get(SystemProperties.java:52)
    at com.htc.customization.HtcCustomizationManager.<init>(HtcCustomizationManager.java:65)
    at com.htc.customization.HtcCustomizationManager.<clinit>(HtcCustomizationManager.java:60)
    at android.os.Environment$UserEnvironment.getCustomizationReader(Environment.java:523)
    at android.os.Environment$UserEnvironment.isDynamicSwitchSupported(Environment.java:534)
    at android.os.Environment$UserEnvironment.<init>(Environment.java:222)
    at android.os.Environment.initForCurrentUser(Environment.java:142)
    at android.os.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:136)
    at android.os.Environment.getLegacyExternalStorageDirectory(Environment.java:726)
    at android.os.Debug.<clinit>(Debug.java:96)
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleHELO(DdmHandleHello.java:164)
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:91)
    at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleFEAT(DdmHandleHello.java:176)
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:93)
    at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleMPRQ(DdmHandleProfiling.java:215)
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleChunk(DdmHandleProfiling.java:106)
    at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
Aborted 

Error while Launching activity
```

I updated Android Studio to 2.0 recently, This is the error I get sometimes. 
When I Clean and Rerun the application. The application runs smoothly.

**Update:** API version is 23. I run the project directly into my HTC one M8.

Comment: This happened to me in older Android Studio too.

Comment: @chabislav how did u get rid of it ?

Comment: To be honest I didn't. I just updated to 2.0 and sometimes I just get this error...

Comment: This really isn't the format of a StackOverflow question. I realize your question is "how do I fix it", but maybe you should file a bug report for Android Studio instead

Comment: I will do that. Thank @cricket_007

Comment: when you upgraded to 2.0 did you got an error Jdk version not matching.To use android studio 2.0 please use jdk1.8.I faced similar problem.I updated jdk1.6  to 1.8 and my problem was solved